# what should be data type for the Enumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding

I am using mvc 3 razor and problem is recording the dropdownlist value in database using razor helpers:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Question,   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.QuestionList)
```

Here, My view is using model binding. while in database the question column is of sting data type (varchar) and while running application it shows following erros after submitting form

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'Question' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

What should I change here to avoid erros here I have to use model binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I change here to avoid erros here I have to use model binding.

You should ensure that inside the controller action that rendered this view you have populated the `ViewBag.QuestionList` property with an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. People usually forget to do this in their POST actions when redisplaying the same view containing this DropDown:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = ... 
ViewBag.QuestionList = items;
return View(someModel);
```

Also make sure that the Question property on your model is a scalar type (string, integer, ...) and not a complex type. If it is a complex type you need to select the corresponding scalar property to bind the selected value to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Question.QuestionId, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.QuestionList
)
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, I forgot to pass the viewbag item in HTTPOST action. thanks!!